# Start daemon process from cron job

Tags: cron

I have been trying for a few hours to do the following (on Centos 6):

1. cron starts process A
2. process A checks if process B is alive
3. if process B is not alive, process A starts process B

The problem is that after process A terminates, process B is terminated as well.

Process A and Process B are both bash running a script.

I have been trying to use `bin/bash script.sh &` and `exec bin/bash script.sh` both without success. If I start process A from the console, process B is not terminated.

Is what I am trying to do theoretically possible (e.g. have a process be started from a process launched from cron and have it survive). In which other ways could I start process B to have it survive the termination of process A?

Answer (score 1):

use `nohup scriptForB.sh` inside scriptForA.sh... in that way, the child process will not be terminated when the parent process exits..

On termination, parent process will send `SIGTERM` signal to all child process. If you use `nohup`, the child process will ignore the `SIGTERM` signals.

Comment: Actually, it's the `SIGHUP` that is ignored - hence the name `nohup`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `nohup`. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I call from cron `nohup run_daemon_from_cron.sh &`. In `run_daemon_from_cron.sh` I call `nohup run_daemon.sh &`. The process created in run_daemon.sh is still destroyed. If I call `run_daemon_from_cron.sh` in a serial console, the daemon is started correctly.

Comment: I added in `run_daemon_from_cron.sh` a few statements like `trap "echo 1 >> /testlog;exit" 1` (for 1,2,3,9,15) but it generates no output.

Comment: I was having a very similar issue starting a node app in my script. The solution turned out to be: add cd /home/domain/path to where the second script exists.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve this problem but this is the **workaround** which worked for me:

1. I defined a new script `run.sh` which does something as the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   while true
   do
      run_process_a.sh
      sleep 60
   done
   ```
2. Then I defined a couple of other scripts

   - `service.sh`: A [daemon script](http://shahmirj.com/blog/the-initd-script)
   - `start.sh`: A wrapper to start an instance of run.sh and store its pid
   - `stop.sh`: A wrapper to stop an instance of run.sh through the stored pid
3. I registered service.sh with init.d and through chkconfig

As said, this is not a direct answer to my questions but it helped me solve my problem which is why I record it here. Also, this might be the cleaner approach to achieve what I intend.